# How to query a 2 table database in Codeigniter

Tags: php, mysql, database, codeigniter

I have 2 tables in a single database.

For example:

```
Table 1 Columns:
id | code | name

Table 2 Columns:
id | code | family | etc.
```

How can I query both tables based on the overlapping code column to retrieve family column?

This is what I currently have:

```
$query = $this->db
    ->select('*')
    ->from('table 1')
    ->where('code', '123');

$query->get()->result();
```

The above query will retrieve the row(s) with code 123 but I'd like to get the corresponding family data from table 2. How can I do this?

Comment: While it is certainly possible to perform the query using a similar method I prefer to use `$this->db->query()` and [create the sql myself](http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/database/queries.html).  At least for me it was less confusing and got me more familiar with writing queries.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use join(). Something like:

```
$query = $this->db
    ->select('*')
    ->from('table1')
    ->join('table2', 'table1.code = table2.code')
    ->where('code', '123');
```

Docs on the function are here: http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/database/active_record.html#select

Answer (score 0):

well you must add a sentence Join, it will let you query two tables.

```
$dataquery = array('table1.code' => '123'); //var in order to where
$this->db->select('table1.id As id1, table2.id As id2') //separate the ids with names
$this->db->join('table2.code','tabla1.code'); //code is overlapping
$query = $this->db->get_where('table1',$dataquery);

return $query->get()->result_array();//Return array if you want
```

Cheers!